# Why can't I find any documentation on Aws::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-ruby

SQS client raises `Aws::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue` error when queue is not found. But, why

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SQS/Errors.html This doc doesn't mention a thing about it. However, I found it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueUrl.html#API_GetQueueUrl_Errors. But, this is a general api doc, not specific to Ruby.

Is documentation missing, is there a simple way to find what errors are being thrown?

Comment: I'm surprised it does not raise `QueueDoesNotExist` but this part: *"Additionally, error classes are dynamically generated for service errors based on the error code if they are not defined above."* explains the rest

Answer (score 0):

The docs were likely generated with [yard](https://yardoc.org/) however digging through the git repo I was only able to find version 2x tags and no version 3 tagged anywhere.  Only thing I could find was [this commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/commit/a3a2fb54d32d7f1139d3d6d602535d698ebfb145) which added the feature specs. Somehow it seems this never made it into the yard code in docs.  I'm not sure what version 3 is referring to.